# Can you identify this LEGO Space build from the early 90s?

Tags: set-identification

Can anybody help me identify this LEGO model from this old picture. My son built this around late 80's / early 90's. The closest I can find is the [6956 Stella Recon Voyager](https://brickset.com/sets/6956-1/Stellar-Recon-Voyager) set. Same colours and similar pieces. Has he perhaps joined up two sets and made this himself as I cannot find it anywhere. I am looking for parts inventory and instructions. I have a huge box of LEGO pieces I now want to pass on to my grandson. Sorry that the picture is not clearer.

[image]

Update:

Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I have managed to download the parts inventory and instructions for 6956. You are correct with 6886. I now definitely remember buying that for our son and those parts are in the box but I'm not too sure about 1968 it doesn't look familiar. I will have to ask my son who now lives abroad. It appears that, at the time the picture was taken, my son might have used his very active 10yr old imagination! Thank you for that info. I am also going to upload the only other picture I have taken from a different angle if this helps further. So, if I could just find out from what model those large black flat 'fins' and other side pieces might be from I think we might have solved the puzzle.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on [Slope 33 3 x 6 with MTron Logo Print - Red](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3939p68/slope-33-3-x-6-with-mtron-logo-print/4/) which only comes in 1 set: [6956-1: Stellar Recon Voyager](https://rebrickable.com/sets/6956-1/stellar-recon-voyager/) this is the set you already mentioned.

[image]

I see a part that looks like: [Flexible Hose 8.5L with Tabless Ends (Ends same color as Tube)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/73590c01a/flexible-hose-85l-with-tabless-ends-ends-same-color-as-tube/) in trans yellow. which come in several sets. I think it's [1968-1 - Space Expressssic Space 1968-1](https://rebrickable.com/sets/1968-1/space-express/) as this set also contain some white wedge pieces, which look like used at both sides.

[image]

Based on [Windscreen 10 x 4 x 2 1/3 Canopy - Trans-Red](https://rebrickable.com/parts/2507/windscreen-10-x-4-x-2-13-canopy/36/) and [Hinge Vehicle Roof Holder 1 x 4 - Blue](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4315/hinge-vehicle-roof-holder-1-x-4/1/) [6886-1 - Galactic Peace Keeper](https://rebrickable.com/sets/6886-1/galactic-peace-keeper/#parts) is also is the collection

[image]

The rest parts is a lot harder to identify.